# Copy an online hyperlinked image from Microsoft Word to Gmail

Tags: microsoft-word, gmail, copy-paste

I have inserted an image from a URL into a long Word paragraph by going into INSERT - PICTURES, then pasting the URL of the image into the filename box and clicking ENTER.

Next I put a hyperlink behind this image by selecting it, clicking Ctrl - K then inserting a hyperlink, then clicking OK.

Now, I want to copy the long paragraph (including this linked image) and paste it into Gmail. The final output should be:

1) The same image in the same location in the paragraph coming from the same source, or simply uploaded into Gmail images.
2) Clicking on this image in Gmail will go to the same hyperlink

I tried it with just normal copy and paste but the image is not even copied, let alone the hyperlink.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Attaching a screenshot of what you are trying to do would be very helpful since I can't really see what you are trying to copy and paste. Please edit your post using the link above and press Ctrl+G to attach a screenshot showing the exact content you are trying to copy to the clipboard.

Comment: Added a screenshot, @AndrewLau

Comment: Whether this is on-topic here or not depends on whether the reason the OP cannot copy this content is a fault of Word, his web browser, or the Gmail service. It's only off-topic if it's *only* the latter...and I doubt that.